# how to remove dynamically loaded images in javascript

Tags: javascript, removechild

I'm loading in 3 images (named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3jpg) dynamically to 3 divs called "div1", "div2" and "div3".

```
function loadImages() {

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "vegetables/"+i+".jpg";
    img.id = "a"+i+"";
    var divName = "div"+i+"";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(img);
}

}
```

That works, but the removing part I can't seem to get to work..

```
function removeImages() {

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var oldImages = "a"+i+"";  
    var divName = "div"+i+"";
    document.getElementById(divName).removeChild(oldImages);
}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery or any other javascript library? They make manipulating the DOM a lot easier.

Comment: yeah I'm still having a bit of trouble with this.. is there a specific plugin for it? could you please link me to the relevant page? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In remove,

```
document.getElementById(divName).removeChild(document.getElementById(oldImages));
```

`removeChild` takes a DOM element, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

In your removal, "oldImages" is just a string saying "a1" or whatever. The parameter to .removeChild needs to be an actual DOM element. You need to either find it again (using document.getElementById or by traversing the children of the div node) or keep around the references to the image element.

Comment: I don't know who did the drive-by downranking here, but Ben is right. Just restoring order ...