# Loading and removing images with DOM, Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to DOM and I'm having trouble removing multiple images that I loaded

this loads 7 images (1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc..)

```
function loadImages() {

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) { 
        var img = document.createElement("img"); 
        img.src = "images/"+i+".jpg";
        var idName = "img"+i+"";
        document.getElementById(idName).appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

this *should* remove all of them, but doesn't.. I think it breaks at the removeChild line.

```
function removeImages() {   

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) { 
        var idName = "img"+i+"";
        var d = document.getElementById(idName);
        d.removeChild(document.getElementById(img));
    }
}
```

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, because I don't fully understand how this works...

Comment: didn't you ask the same question before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467056/how-to-remove-dynamically-loaded-images-in-javascript

Comment: yes, a similar one.. but later realized it wasn't working as it should and couldn't figure it out for the life of me. sorted now, thank you very much! next time I will use the jquery one, but I wanted unique id's for each section.. long story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `removeImages` function the variable `img` is not initialized. And even if it was you don't set the id for any of the images in the `loadImages` function. You could modify your code like this:

```
function loadImages() {

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) { 
        var img = document.createElement("img"); 
        img.src = "images/"+i+".jpg";
        img.id = i;
        var idName = "img"+i+"";
        document.getElementById(idName).appendChild(img);
    }
}

function removeImages() {   

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) { 
        var d = document.getElementById(i);
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code example implies that you're trying to remove a child element of the image and not the image itself. Also, you're using the wrong variable to reference the image. Maybe it works when you replace this line:

```
    d.removeChild(document.getElementById(img));
```

With this:

```
    d.parent.removeChild(document.getElementById(idName));
```

Also, if you're not that familiar with the DOM tree, you might want to take a look at jQuery, which is more browser-independent than regular DOM instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing DOM manipulation, I would recommend that you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or at least try it out).

It will make your life more pleasant, you will be a happier person and it will prevent you from committing harakiri.

Comment: @pablochan: I'm not really into the details. I never tried it :-). BTW, I think your answer is obviously more correct than mine, but the OP should definitely give up on "raw" javascript unless he/she has a reason not to use jQuery or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, JQuery is way cooler than pure JS DOM, but knowing how it works won't hurt :)